# DataTable display hide columns as rows like on https://datatables.net frontpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, show-hide

I've been having issues to work with DataTable. The output I am expecting to achieve is similar to the first example on DataTables.net when you click on the plus icon you can see some information that was in a hide column as a row.

I have an api that returns an array of data of this structure

```
[
  {id: 1, 
   state: { name: text, ...},
   user: { name: text, last_name: text},
   fail: 0, (default)
   reason: text (null when fail = 0), 
   description: text (null when fail = 0), 
   requirements: text (null when fail = 0),
   created_at: date
  }
]
```

The columns reason, description and requirements are filled sometimes under certain cases and I would like to display that information after clicking on a plus button.

I was filling the table with Javascript once the Ajax request was completed. I at the beginning had just three columns to display state.name, user.name + user.lastname, and created_at.

```
var html = '';
for(var i = 0; i < states.length; i++){
 var state = states[i];
 html += '<tr>';
 html += '<td>'+ state.state.name + '</td>';
 html += '<td>'+ state.user.name + ' '+ state.user.last_name + '</td>';
 html += '<td>'+ state.created_at + '</td>';
 html += '</tr>';
}
if($.fb.DataTable.isDataTable('#table-states')){
 $('#table-states').DataTable().clear().destroy();
}
$('#table-states tbody').html(html).DataTable({
 "scrollY": '200px',
 "scrollCollapse': true,
 "paging": false,
 "searching": false,
 "info": false
});
```

This was working perfectly but when I tried to add the 3 others columns with a dynamic row, I started to have problems. What I did was a change in the for loop.

```
var html = '';
for(var i = 0; i < states.length; i++){
 var state = states[i];
 html += '<tr>';
 html += '<td>'+ state.state.name + '</td>';
 html += '<td>'+ state.user.name + ' '+ state.user.last_name + '</td>';
 html += '<td>'+ state.created_at + '</td>';
 html += '</tr>';
 if(state.fail){
  html += '<tr class="hide"><td colspan="3">';
  html += '<strong>Reason:</strong> ' + state.reason +'<br>';
  html += '<strong>Description:</strong> ' + state.description + '<br>';
  html += '<strong>Requirements:<strong> ' + state.requirements;
  html += '</td></tr>';
 }
}
```

I additionally have added buttons and event oriented programming to show or hide the row accordingly. The problem that I now have is that the options I was passing to initialize the DataTable is no longer taken in considerations and I no longer have a height of 200px with scroll which is crucial considering the amount of rows I could have sometimes.

Please help to achieve this outcome, hopefully using columnDefs as DataTable's frontpage shows or with javascript as I was trying

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in [this Link](https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html)  showing example of show and hide row in Data table.